# Getting map from purrr to work with paste0

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have 9 lists with objects groupings$ag under them. I'm trying to extract that object from each of the 9 lists, and make those into columns into a tibble/df. First column should have Groups 1:5. Subsequent 9 columns each a simple vector with 5 numbers. Sorry this isn't complete & reproducible..

`map(hof2009_ag$groupings, "ag") %>% unlist` will correctly give me a vector

```
[1] 789 615 525 425 352
```

but it fails to work if I use map with paste0 dynamically:
`map(paste0("hof", i,"_ag$groupings"), "ag")`.

So, I am trying to get the 9 lists, titled hof2009:hof2017, mapped through a for loop using the iterator to access each. When I try to use paste0 to dynamically create my hof(i)_ag$groupings, it no longer works with map.

```
ag <- tibble(group=1:5)
for (i in 2009:2017) {
temp <- paste0("hof", i,"_ag$groupings") #works, "hof2009_ag$groupings"
TEST <- temp %>% map("ag") %>% unlist #fails, produces NULL
TEST <- hof2009_ag$groupings %>% map("ag") %>% unlist #works, produces 789 615 525 425 352
#ag <- map(temp, "ag") %>% unlist #doesn't work on "temp"
}
```

A second issue is how to get these to add as columns. I've played with add_column and mutate and ag[,i-2008], but can't get it to work as long as map doesn't work with paste.

If I use :

```
mget(paste0("hof", 2009:2009, "_ag")) %>%
map("groupings") %>% str
```

I get:

```
List of 1
 $ hof2009_ag:List of 5
 ..$ :List of 6
 .. ..$ prefs   :'data.frame':  14 obs. of  1 variable:
.. .. ..$ rank: int [1:14] 0 3 3 4 1 0 1 2 1 0 ...
.. ..$ ag      : int 789
.. ..$ grp     : int [1:60] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
.. ..$ iters   : num 1
.. ..$ run_time: Named num 1.13
.. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "elapsed"
..$ :List of 6
.. ..$ prefs   :'data.frame':   14 obs. of  2 variables:
.. .. ..$ rank  : int [1:14] 0 3 4 5 2 1 2 3 1 1 ...
.. .. ..$ rank.1: int [1:14] 2 4 4 5 1 0 3 3 2 1 ...
.. ..$ ag      : int 615
.. ..$ grp     : int [1:60] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
.. ..$ iters   : num 4
.. ..$ run_time: Named num 5.61
.. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "elapsed"
```

Edit: example using dput

```
> dput(hof2009_ag)
```

list(decision_makers = c("Phil.Arvia", "Steve.Aschburner", "Filip.Bondy", "Bob.Verdi"), alternatives = c("Harold.Baines", "Bert.Blyleven", "Alan.Trammell"
), number_decision_makers = 60L, num_alts = 14L, groupings = list(list(prefs = structure(list(rank = c(0L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Harold.Baines", "Bert.Blyleven", "Alan.Trammell")), ag = 789L, grp = c(1L, 1L, 1L), iters = 1, run_time = c(elapsed = 1.12999999999738), grp2 = structure(list(Decision_Maker = c("Phil.Arvia", "Steve.Aschburner", "Filip.Bondy", "Dave.Van.Dyck", "Bob.Verdi"), Group_Number = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1")), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(prefs = structure(list(rank = c(0L, 3L, 2L), rank.1 = c(2L, 4L,  2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Harold.Baines", "Bert.Blyleven", "Andre.Dawson", "Alan.Trammell"), ag = 615L, grp = c(1L, 1L, 1L), iters = 4, run_time = c(elapsed = 5.61000000000058),  grp2 = structure(list(Decision_Maker = c("Phil.Arvia", "Steve.Aschburner", "Steve.Wilmoth", "Dave.Van.Dyck", "Bob.Verdi"), Group_Number = c("1", "1",        "1", "1")), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",         "data.frame"))), list(prefs = structure(list(rank = c(0L, 3L, 1L, 1L), rank.1 = c(0L, 4L,  2L), rank.2 = c(1L, 2L, 2L))

Comment: It is better to use `[[` instead of `$`.  also, if these objects are in the global env, use `mget` i.e. `mget(paste0("hof", 2009:2017, "_ag")) %>% map(~ .x %>% select(groupings)) %>% unlist`  Not clear without a small reproducible example though

Comment: Quick clarification: my object is under hof_2009:2017$groupings$ag. So should map be selecting groupings, then ag? I think a small tweak of your code may do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reproducible example would be useful.  Based on the code showed, get the objects in the global environment using `mget` and `paste`, then loop through the `list` elements, `select` the 'groupings' `list` element and 'ag' (nested `list`) with `$` or `[[`

```
library(tidyverse)
mget(paste0("hof", 2009:2017, "_ag")) %>%
        map(~ map(.x$groupings, ~ .x$ag))
```

Comment: This may help.. groupings is a sub-list under hof2009_ag. And ag is a list under groupings. So neither are columns. Do I then double map? Like such: 
$hof2017_ag$groupings[[5]]$`ag`
[1] 5173

Comment: Ahh almost. I think the mapping needs to be done within groupings because there is no groupings$ag, only groupings[[i]]$ag. So somehow 5 groupings need to be split before ag is extracted

Comment: @DSchiff  Can you check the output of `mget(paste0("hof", 2009:2017, "_ag")) %>% map(~ .x$groupings %>% map(.x %>% pull('ag')))`

Comment: You bet: no luck yet! Error in UseMethod("pull") : no applicable method for 'pull' applied to an object of class "list"

Comment: @DSchiff  can you please update your post with a small example using `dput` so that I can test it

Comment: Added it - tell me if it doesn't work. I just did 2 groups' worth, so there should be just 2 $groupings$ag entries: hof2009_ag$groupings[[1]]$ag and hof2009_ag$groupings[[2]]$ag

Comment: @DSchiff  Can you try with the edited post.  This is based on your dput

Comment: Nice! Last question. I was able to unlist this as a single vector with %>% unlist %>% as.vector. Is there a simple way to get those 5*9 ag entries into 9 columns of a tibble? ag2 <- tibble(num_groups=1:5, c(2009:2017)) where each of 2009:2017 has their respective 5 ag entries?